# How to shorten runtime of this iteration problem

Tags: c++

I have the snippet of C++ below which iterates over 1-50 and prints out a statement, instead of the number, if the element is divisible by either 2 or 3. The current runtime is ~1.47 seconds. How can I optimize this problem for a faster run?

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (int j = 1; j <= 50; j++)
    {
        if (j % 2 == 0 && j % 3 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Both" << std::endl;
        }

        else if (j % 2 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Two" << std::endl;
        }

        else if (j % 3 == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Three" << std::endl;
        }

        else
        {
            std::cout << j << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean compile time, and not run time? Both should just take less than a blink of an eye anyways.

Comment: Yes i meant runtime. Thank you. Runs in 1.4 seconds... a bit slow atm

Comment: 1.4 seconds for simple math and 50 prints?  Is your computer hamster powered?

Comment: Running an i7 with 32gb ram and 1080... maybe the extension I'm using on vs code to run the code is spitting out the incorrect runtime

Comment: @Farnsworth That hardly can be true. How did you measure that? What's your OS / CPU?

Comment: You can try to stop using endl. It is really slow. [Here is a video talking about that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMqQOEZYVJQ)

Comment: @Pablochaches That's a _cargo cult mysticism_. The difference would be a few milliseconds or even nanoseconds for any decent modern terminal implementetions or CPUs.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: A few milliseconds times 50 adds up.  You might hope that the cost of a flush gets down into microseconds if going to a terminal or an SSD, but nanoseconds is just wishful thinking.  I/O flush is rather expensive.

Comment: Use a high precision clock like [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) to get precise time for your function

Comment: Increase the baud rate.

Comment: The problem you are solving is traditionally called **FizzBuzz**, which you can search the web for.

Comment: For an interesting data point, might want to measure how long does `int main() {}` take?  Or how long does it take if you remove all the `cout` statements?

Comment: I'd argue, that it must be the console. Windows `cmd` is pretty slow, I guess. I cant believe the problem has to do with the code.

Comment: _maybe the extension I'm using on vs code_ ... so what extension **are** you using on vscode?

Answer (score 2):

You can change `endl` inside the loop to `"\n"`, and then `std::cout << std::flush;` after the loop completes.  This will reduce the number of flushes by a factor of 50.

Since flushing output is the only non-trivial work going on here, I expect that to reduce your runtime by 98%.  However I would have expected that even with 50 flushes it still should be well under a second.

Comment: And since I/O is almost always the source of slowdown, I will believe this.  But I still don't believe this runs at 1.4 seconds originally...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Well maybe if the output is piped to some sort of automatic testing framework (like the `expect` tool) and the 1.4 seconds is wall-clock time not the time spent by his program alone.

Comment: Ok, removing endl changed the runtime to ~1.2 seconds. Adding the flush statement doesn't seem to speed things along, still ~1.2 s.

Comment: I am betting his reporting tool is giving him micro seconds or something.  Or he has 10 anti-virus programs and his system is completely owned...

Comment: @Farnsworth: I don't expect adding flush to speed things up, it's just restoring the behavior you lost by taking out `endl`.

Comment: I am using the "coderunner" extension for vs code btw

Comment: @BenVoigt Just noteworthy that most line buffered implementations today would  automatically`flush()` on appearance of `'\n'` as well nowadays.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Most implementations are line-buffered only if connected to a TTY.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **do not try to optimice struff before you really need it** (Keep that point in mind). I really do not believe that that code takes 1.4 seconds to run. But ok.

The only thing that I can see that you can make better is to separate then in groups at compile time. That way you will not calculate the modulo for every number, you will just see if you need to print text or not.

So what i did was to create a function evaluated at compile time that returns a `const char*` with the text if it is needed, or with nullprt if it is not:

```
constexpr const char *type(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0 && n % 3 == 0) {
        return "Both";
    }

    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return "Two";
    }

    if (n % 3 == 0) {
        return "Three";
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

Next I have an array with all the needed results:

```
const int max_number = 50;
constexpr const static std::array<const char *, max_number + 1> results{
    type(0),
    type(1),
    type(2),
    type(3),
    type(4),
    type(5),
    type(6),
    type(7),
    type(8),
    type(9),
    type(10),
    type(11),
    type(12),
    type(13),
    type(14),
    type(15),
    type(16),
    type(17),
    type(18),
    type(19),
    type(20),
    type(21),
    type(22),
    type(23),
    type(24),
    type(25),
    type(26),
    type(27),
    type(28),
    type(29),
    type(30),
    type(31),
    type(32),
    type(33),
    type(34),
    type(35),
    type(36),
    type(37),
    type(38),
    type(39),
    type(40),
    type(41),
    type(42),
    type(43),
    type(44),
    type(45),
    type(46),
    type(47),
    type(48),
    type(49),
    type(50)
};
```

The result of this is that when the program is compiled, you already have then separated into gropus. You can see it [here](https://godbolt.org/z/rd9W5d). The resulting assembler will be something like this:

```
.L.str:
        .asciz  "Both"

.L.str.2:
        .asciz  "Two"

.L.str.3:
        .asciz  "Three"

results:
        .quad   .L.str // 0 both
        .quad   0 // 1 none
        .quad   .L.str.2 // 2 Two
        .quad   .L.str.3 // 3 Three
        .quad   .L.str.2 // 4 Two
        .quad   0  // 5 none
        .quad   .L.str // etc
        .quad   0
        // ...  and it continues for all values
```

And finaly at runtime you just check if it is null or not:

```
int main() {
    Timer t{};
    for (int j = 1; j <= max_number; j++) {
        if (results[j]) {
            cout << results[j] << '\n';
        } else {
            cout << j << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

***Results:***

- The original way took 0.05 to 0.08 miliseconds in my machine.
- The new way took 0.04 to 0.07 miliseconds.

So yes, it is faster. But that fast that it will change anything.

Now I really want to get this point clear. **Do not optimize before you need it!**. Here is a [quick bech](https://quick-bench.com/q/9PKly_0vHJibO980cMZHEnNh7aY) with both of them compiled with `-O3`. The diference is really minimal and the code is a lot more bigger and complicated. Prefer the simple way

Comment: ok, thank you. The issue seems to be the VS code extension I am using to compile. The runtime it is outputting is not accurate.

Comment: Well the question was about optimization. This was the only thing that came into my mind. Good luck with your extension, hope you can make it work

Comment: Funny enough - unroll the loop and precompute the values.  And yes it is faster for what it is worth :)

Answer (score 0):

I hardly believe it to be that slow on any i7. Should run in at most a few milliseconds.

Yet, the question is 'how to improve' and for that there are a few bits:

1. turn on optimization `-O2`
2. remove `std::cout` in loops. Instead create a e.g. `std::string`, append output to that variable in the loop and after the loop, output it. Measure only the loop, not the `std::cout`
3. use nested loops, like @MichaelDorgan suggested.

Comment: Measuring only the loops I think defeats the original question as it measures a different amount of time with I/O.  Even including the I/O though, there is something else going on.   BTW, at -O2, the compiler probably can hide anything related to not nesting the loops - again because the math is so simple.

Answer (score 0):

Only 50 iterations?  Unroll it into a state machine (50 states, 1 switch statement, no maths).  Or, turn it into a single print of precomputed values.  Still does not answer why the program runs as slow as it does though...

Comment: I'm starting to think it may have to do with the vs extension I'm using...

Answer (score 0):

The same code takes 12-66ms to run on my machine. I think that the problem is in your time measurement. You can measure your runtime with C++'s standard facilities such as `chrono` library:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<chrono>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    using clock = chrono::high_resolution_clock;

    auto start = clock::now();

    for (int j = 1; j <= 50; j++) {
        if (j % 2 == 0 && j % 3 == 0) {
            cout << "Both" << endl;
        } else if (j % 2 == 0) {
            cout << "Two" << endl;
        } else if (j % 3 == 0) {
            cout << "Three" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << j << endl;
        }
    }

    auto end = clock::now();
    cout << "Total runtime: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << "ms." << endl;
}
```

This code will measure the duration of the actual loop in milliseconds and print it. It will ignore any overhead for the program starting, initializing and stopping, and will let you know about the actual code performance, not the OS' process running facilities performance. I bet it will show a great increase of speed, for me it prints "Total runtime: 4ms." in the end.